# Firebase Firestore and Authentication Errors

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

After I added the firestore dependency it stopped working. I need both of them(firestore and auth), tried with more versions, and different one, but right now they are the last ones.

Here is the Authentication errors that I get:

> W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@ad3ce63
>   W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
>   W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 11743470

And the Firestore error:

> W/Firestore: (18.1.0) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

I have these dependencies, maybe they won't work togheter I think?

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.philliphsu:bottomsheetpickers:2.4.1'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Edit:

> Solution: The problem was Google play Services, which I updated, and now my app is working.

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the internet?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: Check again otherwise you don't get an error like this: `Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend.`.

Comment: I checked, my emulator is connected, maybe the code is the problem?

Comment: Show us the code that you are using.

Comment: Check all permissions for Internet like :-   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: I'm still getting same errors, after I was replacing all permisions, even if it had only  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: I put the code below, @AlexMamo

Comment: Your code looks good to me. So it's either a permission problem you an internet connection issue.

Comment: I don't know, I'm stuck at this for so many hours, when it had the dependency version 10.0.6 it worked good, but i had only the Core and Auth dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to the Manifest?

Comment: Yes, it has the permission

Answer (score 0):

it might be  you forget gms service, but i am not sure. Try this and give me a feedback. Thanks, ..

```
// Firestore
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'

// Other Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
```

Comment: Just edited yesterday the solution to my problem, I don't think it had a problem with 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0', but thank you anyway. Apreciated it!